# c shellcode: how to use syscall

Tags: gdb, x86-64, system-calls, inline-assembly, shellcode

I tried to make shell code with syscall

```
void main()
{
    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
     "movq $0x0068732f6e69622f, %rdx \n\t"
     "pushq %rdx \n\t"
     "movq $0x3b, %rax \n\t"
     "movq %rsp, %rdi \n\t"
     "movq %rsp, %rdx \n\t"
     "pushq %rdi \n\t"
     "lea 0x0(%rsp), %rsi \n\t"
     "movq $0x2a, %r10 \n\t"
     "movq $0x2, %r8 \n\t"
     "movq $0x6, %r9 \n\t"
     "syscall \n\t"
     "pop %rdi \n\t"
     "pop %rdx \n\t"
     );
}
```

This is my source

It compiled successfully.

But It doesn't execute sh function which I aimed

Is there any problem with code???

Comment: Can you detail the code with some comments?  I thought syscall used eax, ebx and ecx for arguments.  Running your program shows eax with a 59 which would be sys_olduname according to this: http://docs.cs.up.ac.za/programming/asm/derick_tut/syscalls.html

Comment: I purposed to run execve function with syscal. According to [link] (https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/) 59 represents execve which I aimed. I use Ubuntu 16.04 and x64 architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, taken from [here](https://codinguy.net/2013/09/30/execve-shellcode-64-bit/) and spiffed up a bit.

```
void main()
{
    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
      "xor %rdi,%rdi \n\t"
      "push %rdi \n\t"
      "push %rdi \n\t"
      "pop %rsi \n\t"
      "pop %rdx \n\t"
      "movq $0x68732f6e69622f2f,%rdi \n\t"
      "shr $0x08,%rdi \n\t"
      "push %rdi \n\t"
      "push %rsp \n\t"       
      "pop %rdi \n\t" 
      "push $0x3b \n\t"
      "pop %rax \n\t"          
      "syscall \n\t"
     );
}
```

Your assembler is similar but seems to go awry on the $rdi and $rdx load.  The working code sets them to NULL (0) before the syscall.  This [link](http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/) indicates that the exec call takes three parameters apparently the second two can be null.

I did the set with your code and it worked!

```
void main()
{
    __asm__ __volatile__
    (
     "movq $0x0068732f6e69622f, %rdx \n\t"
     "pushq %rdx \n\t"
     "movq $0x3b, %rax \n\t"
     "movq %rsp, %rdi \n\t"
     "movq %rsp, %rdx \n\t"
     "pushq %rdi \n\t"
     "lea 0x0(%rsp), %rsi \n\t"
     "movq $0x2a, %r10 \n\t"
     "movq $0x2, %r8 \n\t"
     "movq $0x6, %r9 \n\t"
     "movq $0x0, %rsi \n\t"
     "movq $0x0, %rdx \n\t"
     "syscall \n\t"
     "pop %rdi \n\t"
     "pop %rdx \n\t"
     );
}
```

Fun little puzzle, gave me a chance to brush up on my assembler :)

Comment: Sure. I'd appreciate it if you could 'accept' the answer and up vote it. I'm trying to build my reputation :)